# Add variables to DataFrame through iteration

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a predefined DataFrame df to which I assign value x based on the location provided by value y and z

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y = [5000, 5300, 1200, 5300]
z = [3000, 3000, 5300, 3000]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns= [1200,3000,5000,5300], index = [1200,3000,5000,5300]) 

for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z):
    df.at[b,c] = a
```

I intent to get the Dataframe:

```
Index 1200 3000 5000 5300
1200   x     x    x    C
3000   x     x    x    x
5000   x     A    x    x
5300   x     B    x    x         
             D
```

But using the provided code I only get

```
Index 1200 3000 5000 5300
1200   x     x    x    C
3000   x     x    x    x
5000   x     A    x    x           
5300   x     D    x    x
```

How can I add a value when there has been added a value in a previous iteration?

Comment: What is supposed to appear at `[5000, 3000]`? Both `A` and `B`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Yes, ```[5000, 3000]```should in this case include both ```A``` and ```B```

Comment: OK, but how? Do you want the index `5000` repeated twice?

Comment: Just noticed it's index `5300` and that you're asking for it to contain both `B` and `D`. So...you'd like it to contain `BD`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
y = [5000, 5300, 1200, 5300]
z = [3000, 3000, 5300, 3000]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns= [1200,3000,5000,5300], index = [1200,3000,5000,5300]) 

for a,b,c in zip(x,y,z):
    if df.at[b,c] is np.nan:
        df.at[b,c] = a
    else:
        df.at[b,c] += a
```